# How to connect local ganache node with epirus

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache, docker, epirus

I tried [apirus](https://github.com/blk-io/epirus-free) to connect to local ganache node.

Ganache node is running on localhost:7545.

```
git clone https://github.com/blk-io/epirus-free.git
cd epirus-free
docker-compose pull
NODE_ENDPOINT=http://docker0:7545 docker-compose up
```

But couldn't connect.  Error log says docker0 is unknowHost.

```
api_1      | 2020-03-26 07:05:52.323 ERROR 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
api_1      | 
api_1      | java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: docker0
api_1      |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
api_1      | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: docker0
api_1      |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
api_1      |    at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.kt:49)
api_1      |    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.kt:160)
api_1      |    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.kt:125)
api_1      |    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.kt:7
```

How to connect to local ganache node from docker container ??

Comment: Please elaborate on "But couldn't connect". Also, why have you tagged this question under `truffle`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I fix my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the steps in **blk-io/epirus/README**

Note that if setting **NODE_ENDPOINT** to a local Ethereum instance, you may need to use the **IP address associated with** the Docker bridged interface, often denoted by **docker0**.

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
```

Instead of

`NODE_ENDPOINT=http://docker0:7545 docker-compose up`

it should be

`NODE_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:7545 docker-compose up`

i.e. in place of `docker0` the `inet` value for docker0 has to be placed.